# How do I update a dataframe column with a formula that uses values from other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of investments that shows a value for the investment, a coupon rate, and an annual income. Some investments generate no income, and some investments have a coupon rate but the annual income is not computed. How do I update the income column when there is a valid coupon but no number in the income column? Here is some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numbers

data = {'value':[100, 150, 200, 250], 'coupon':[3,'-',4,5], 'income':[3,'-',8,'-']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Rows 0 and 2 are complete, and don't need updating. Row 1 has no value for income, and no value for coupon, so it also doesn't need updating.

[image: sample dummy data]

Only the income value in the bottom row should be updated, to 12.5.

Like in my dummy data set, the cells without meaningful numbers have dashes in them, they're not empty.

I wrote a function to execute this algorithm, but I don't know how to apply it to the dataframe:

```
def filler(value, coupon, income):
    if ~isinstance(income, numbers.Number) and isinstance(coupon, numbers.Number):
        income = (coupon * value)/100
        return(income)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a loop, not use `-` for missing values.

Remove the `-`, use NaNs, and vectorize your code:

```
df[['coupon', 'income']] = df[['coupon', 'income']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

df['income'] = df['income'].fillna(df['coupon'].mul(df['value']).div(100))
```

Output:

```
   value  coupon  income
0    100     3.0     3.0
1    150     NaN     NaN
2    200     4.0     8.0
3    250     5.0    12.5
```

Comment: Am I correct that vectorizing my code like this will speed it up? It certainly is elegant.

Comment: @Tom yes this will be much faster that a loop or apply (for large datasets)

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numbers

data = {'value':[100, 150, 200, 250], 'coupon':[3,'-',4,5], 'income':[3,'-',8,'-']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def filler(value, coupon, income):
    if not isinstance(income, numbers.Number) and isinstance(coupon, numbers.Number):
        income = (coupon * value) / 100
        return income
    else:
        return income

df['income'] = df.apply(lambda row: filler(row['value'], row['coupon'], row['income']), axis=1)

print(df)
```